# How to convert Bytes Array to a String in order to see it printed onto the console?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to convert a Byte Array to a String in order to be able to see this Vector/Array and analyse how these bytes are organized.

I'm using the code below to do it:

```
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    String msgDecode = new String(bytes); // trying to convert byte in String
    System.out.println("Vetor de bytes [" + msgDecode + "]"); // Showing it
```

But it's not working. Why the code above it's no working?

It is worth mentioning that the Byte Array is being constructed according to this other code here:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";

public byte[] convert(String path) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1; ) {
        bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
    }

    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    return bytes;

}
```

The general idea is to record an audio with the smartphone and convert this audio file to a array of bytes. This String path is the path where the audio is being saved after recording. Then I use this path (that represents the audio file) and convert it to a byte array according to the code above.

More information you can find and help me here: [How to solve this error: Android resource linking failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683290/how-to-solve-this-error-android-resource-linking-failed)

Comment: "But it's not working!!!" meaning what? What did you expect to see and what do you see instead?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it's showing absolutely nothing at the Console or Build/Debug area of Android studio. I wanted to see a real vector with these bytes (different numbers for each vector's element).

Comment: Yes, but how do you want to see them? You can't just print binary data and expect to see something useful. You'll need to loop through the array and print every single byte, for example, as a hexadecimal number representing the byte. Is that what you need?

Comment: some advice: although `System.out.println` is possible, it's not the recommended way to print in Android development. you should use Android's `Log` class instead

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca what you've said it's exactly what I need!

Comment: @IvoBeckers got it! Thanks!

Comment: @user85421 maybe Arrays.toString(byte[ ]) is better to use. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59772285/12309591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'll try to do, based in what you guys said:

```
String decode = Arrays.toString(bytes);
Log.d("mytag", decode);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to see value of bytes you can use as below:

> Log.d("TAG", Arrays.toString(bytes));

Comment: Log also requires a "tag" parameter

Comment: @IvoBeckers I always have doubts about this tag parameter. How it works exactly? It needs to have a specific type? Or it can be any string? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```java
        byte[] bytes = "ABCDEFG".getBytes();
        System.out.println(new String(bytes));      // ABCDEFG
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes)); // [65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71]
```